# Characteristic polynomial of adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, alternative-proof, adjoint-operators

I'm trying to show that the adjoint transformation $T^*$ of the endomorphism $T$ on a finite dimensional, real inner product space has the same characteristic polynomial as $T$ in a coordinate free (so no matrices) way.

Definition of adjoint of endomorphism $T$ on the VS $V$: It's the transformation such that $$\langle T(x), y\rangle = \langle x, T^*(y)\rangle$$ for all $x,y\in V$.

It's easy to show that $(\lambda\ id - T)^* = \lambda\ id - T^*$ where $id$ is the identity transformation but I can't figure out how to either get an explicit expression for $T^*$ or in some other way apply a determinant to a transformation in an inner product.  Any ideas?

Comment: Since the inner product is real, $\det L = \det L^\ast$, and you're done.

Comment: The fact that the determinant of an endomorphism is equal to the determinant of its adjoint is what I'm trying to prove.  I'm just looking at $\det L = \det L$ where $L = \lambda\ id -  T$.  So if you have a good coordinate free proof of that, post it as an answer. :)

Comment: How is it that you are defining determinant and characteristic polynomial without coordinates?

Comment: The only coordinate free way to define $\det$ that I know of is [with exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Abstract_algebraic_aspects).

Comment: I found [an answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804955/coordinate-free-proof-of-determinant-of-transpose).